# How should the Json be for getting following data

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have set of dates.In each date there is a set of names with entry time,exit times. How should the Json format be for displaying it in a listview in android.

> 11/07/2016
>
> Jack 11.20am 10.20pm
>
> John 12.33am 11.32pm

---

> 12/07/2016
>
> Pete 10.20pm 10.00am

and so on...

I am trying to display like this in listview. So for that how should be the Json format and how can i access Json items.

```
            items.add(new Header(j, "Friday - November 30th 2012"));
            items.add(new EventItem(j, "8:30am" , "Start work"));

            items.add(new EventItem(j, "9:15am" , "Call Bob"));
            items.add(new EventItem(j, "11:00am", "Meeting with Joe"));
            items.add(new EventItem(j, "5:00pm" , "Freedom!"));

            items.add(new Header(j, "Saturday - December 1st 2012"));
            items.add(new EventItem(j, "8:30am" , "Keep sleeping"));
            items.add(new EventItem(j, "10:00am", "Wake up"));
            items.add(new EventItem(j, "11:00am", "Walk the dog"));
            items.add(new EventItem(j, "6:00pm" , "Dinner at John's"));

            items.add(new Header(j, "Sunday - December 2rd 2012"));
            items.add(new EventItem(j, "8:30am" , "Keep sleeping"));
            items.add(new EventItem(j, "10:00am", "Wake up"));
            items.add(new EventItem(j, "11:00am", "Walk the dog"));
            items.add(new EventItem(j, "6:00pm" , "Dinner at John's"));

            items.add(new Header(j, "Monday - December 3rd 2012"));
            items.add(new EventItem(j, "8:30am" , "Start work"));
            items.add(new EventItem(j, "9:15am" , "Call Bob"));
            items.add(new EventItem(j, "11:00am", "Meeting with Joe"));
            items.add(new EventItem(j, "5:00pm" , "Freedom!"));
```

This is how i add date and details directly to the list in Java without webservice. 
I am printing attendance of one month. on each date, i need to print the employee name, entry time,exit time

Comment: it will be better if you add json code and some jave code you tried

Comment: There are tools such as http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ to help you build json strings, this might help.

Comment: It doesn't matter. You should use a JSON object mapper (Jackson, for example) to construct a modeled Data Transfer Object. From there, you can create an `ArrayAdapter<YourModeledData>`. You could just follow this howto, replacing "User" with whatever data structure you will use, which is created from JSON. https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: added java code. I need to give an idea of Json code so that php developer can develop it. I dont have a json now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be late to answer since I had to write code for you from scratch haha.. Well check it once,It might help you with how  to access the JSON.

Your JSON would be like this:

```
{
       "items":    [
                  {
                      "name":"Jack",
                      "entryTime":"11.20am",
                      "exitTime":"10.20pm",
                       "date":"11/06/2016"

                  },
                  {
                      "name":"John",
                      "entryTime":"12.33am",
                      "exitTime":"11.32pm",
                     "date":"15/06/2015"
                  },
                  {
                      "name":"Pete",
                      "entryTime":"05.33am",
                      "exitTime":"04.32pm",
                        "date":"09/08/2016"
                  }
               ]

        }
```

Then to access them you need a Model class(POJO),that will hold the data that you want to access from your JSON and show in the listView.

Something like this:

```
 public class Employee{

private String employeeName;
private String entryTime;
private String exitTime;
private String date;

public String getEmployeeName(){
        return employeeName;
        }

public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName){
        this.employeeName=employeeName;
        }
public String getEntryTime(){
        return entryTime;
        }

public void setEntryTime(String entryTime){
        this.entryTime=entryTime;
        }
public String getExitTime(){
        return exitTime;
        }

public void setExitTime(String exitTime){
        this.exitTime=exitTime;
        }

public String getDate(){
        return date;
        }

public void setDate(String date){
        this.date=date;}
        }
```

Now to access them, well, if you are using async task then you can return the response in String.If you want a static JSON then , simply assign the above JSON to a String variable.For example:

```
 String jsonString="{\n" +
           "       \"items\":    [\n" +
           "                  {\n" +
           "                      \"name\":\"Jack\",\n" +
           "                      \"entryTime\":\"11.20am\",\n" +
           "                      \"exitTime\":\"10.20pm\",\n" +
           "                       \"date\":\"11/06/2016\"\n" +
           "\n" +
           "                  },\n" +
           "                  {\n" +
           "                      \"name\":\"John\",\n" +
           "                      \"entryTime\":\"12.33am\",\n" +
           "                      \"exitTime\":\"11.32pm\",\n" +
           "                     \"date\":\"15/06/2015\"\n" +
           "                  },\n" +
           "                  {\n" +
           "                      \"name\":\"Pete\",\n" +
           "                      \"entryTime\":\"05.33am\",\n" +
           "                      \"exitTime\":\"04.32pm\",\n" +
           "                        \"date\":\"09/08/2016\"\n" +
           "                  }\n" +
           "               ]\n" +
           "\n" +
           "        }";
```

Then the JSON can be accessed like:

```
  private ArrayList<Employee> employeeDetails=new ArrayList();/*ArrayList that holds the list data that are to be populated in a listview.*/

        try{
        JSONObject jObj=new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray jArrray=jObj.getJSONArray("items");
        for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
        Employee mEmployee=new Employee();
        JSONObject empDetails=jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String empName=empDetails.getString("name");
        String entryTime=empDetails.getString("entryTime");
        String exitTime=empDetails.getString("exitTime);
String date=empDetails.getString("date");

        mEmployee.setEmployeeName(empName);
        mEmployee.setEntryTime(entryTime);
        mEmployee.setExitTime(exitTime);
        mEmployee.setDate(date);
        employeeDetails.add(mEmployee);/*add data to arraylist*/

        }
    }catch(JSONException e){
    e.printStacktrace();
    }
```

Then you can simply pass the arraylist to the listAdapter and  populate the views.

Comment: like 11/06/2017? and employee details are seperated acccording to dates?

Comment: yep broi. On each date i need to display the employe details.

Comment: Upvote my answer please :). And you can mark it as correct if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I think the JSON will be something like this:

```
{
   [
      {
          "name":"john",
          "in":1489051528,
          "out":1489053000
      },
      {
          "name":"foo",
          "in":1489051528,
          "out":1489053000
      },
      {
          "name":"bar",
          "in":1489051528,
          "out":1489053000
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I need to add date to it. I am printing attendance of one month. on each date, i need to print the employee name, entry time,exit time

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do complex queries on the json dataset (apart from displaying it in ListView) then here is something you can use:

```
{
   "1478457000000": // 11/07/2016
   [
      {
          "name":"jack",
          "in":1478497800000, // 11:20am
          "out":1478537400000 // 10:20pm
      },
      {
          "name":"john",
          "in":1489051528,
          "out":1489053000
      }
   ],

   "1481049000000": // 12/07/2016
   [
      {
          "name":"pete",
          "in":1481129400000, // 10:20pm
          "out":1481085000000// 10:00am
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: wow thanks . this is what i was looking for. Can you help me with getting data from this json . how to extract date and its corresponding data.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question:

> I have set of dates

Okay, so dates are the root element.

> In each date there is a set of names

Each date entry has a sub dictionary of names.

> with entry time,exit times

Each name corresponds to an entry and exit time. So name will map to an object.

In the end, you get something like:

```
{
  "dates": {
    "11/07/2016": {
      "jack": {
        "username": "jack",
        "entry": "11:20am",
        "exit": "10:20pm"
      },
      "john": {
        "username": "john",
        "entry": "12.33am",
        "exit": "11:32pm"
      }
    },
    "12/07/2016": {
      "pete": {
        "username": "pete",
        "entry": "10:20pm",
        "exit": "10:00am"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**IMPROVEMENTS**

- It would be better if `entry` and `exit` were timestamps rather than merely times i.e. `"entry":"2016-07-11T23:32:00"`
- A JSON Dictionary can not have duplicate keys. So you might use a unique username as the key instead of the first name.